Cannot open include file: 'stdio.h': No such file or directory
I am new to C++ and have encountered the following difficulty. I have installed Visual Studio Community 2022 version 17.9.6, in it I have installed the items shown in the screenshot.

Immediately after creating a console application for Windows in C++, I got a lot of errors in the console related to importing files like 'ctype.h', 'errno.h', 'float.h' and so on. I started looking for solutions, but none of them helped me.
Some of what I tried:

change Properties → General → Windows SDK Version to 10 (I've got 10.0 selected by default)
install the "Windows Universal CRT SDK" Visual Studio component

I would be very grateful for the help!
P.S
Screenshot with C++ part

The code i'm using
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}

Project properties page

Errors:
cannot open source file "ctype.h"
cannot open source file "errno.h"
cannot open source file "float.h"
cannot open source file "locale.h"
cannot open source file "corecrt.h"
cannot open source file "stddef.h"
cannot open source file "stdio.h"
cannot open source file "math.h"
cannot open source file "stdlib.h"
cannot open source file "string.h"
cannot open source file "time.h"
cannot open source file "wchar.h"
cannot open source file "corecrt_terminate.h"
cannot open source file "malloc.h"
cannot open source file "share.h"
cannot open source file "crtdbg.h"
the global scope has no "isalnum"
the global scope has no "isalpha"
the global scope has no "iscntrl"
the global scope has no "isdigit"
the global scope has no "isgraph"
the global scope has no "islower"
the global scope has no "isprint"
the global scope has no "ispunct"
the global scope has no "isspace"
the global scope has no "isupper"
the global scope has no "isxdigit"
the global scope has no "tolower"
the global scope has no "toupper"
the global scope has no "isblank"
the global scope has no "Iconv"
the global scope has no "localeconv"
the global scope has no "setlocale"
the global scope has no "acosf"
the global scope has no "asinf"
the global scope has no "atanf"
the global scope has no "atan2f"
the global scope has no "ceilf"
the global scope has no "cosf"
...

And one more error after trying to change SDK version to 10.0.22621.0: 'Error   MSB8036 The Windows SDK version 10.0.22621.0 was not found. Install the required version of Windows SDK or change the SDK version in the project property pages or by right-clicking the solution and selecting "Retarget solution".'
I would like to add that this version is installed in Visual Studio Installer and I have tried reinstalling it. But as I understood, this SDK should be stored in the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits', but there are only directories '8.1' and 'NETFXSDK' there. Maybe these are some old versions and I need to reinstall Visual Studio completely and delete all the old files?
P.S.2
I uninstalled the Windows 11 SDK (10.0.22621.0) and installed the Windows 10 SDK (10.0.20348.0) (I have Windows 11 installed). A bunch of errors disappeared, the required version started showing up in the project settings. I selected it, but then i got an error: 'MSB8036 The Windows SDK version 10.0.20348.0 was not found. Install the required version of Windows SDK or change the SDK version in the project property pages or by right-clicking the solution and selecting 'Retarget solution''. I don't understand how this can happen if Visual Studio itself offers me to select this version.

What were the exact error messages that you received? And what was the code that you used for testing?

<stdio.h> is an include for C language. In C++, we can include <cstdio> in place, but combine C and C++ in a single code is a bad idea.

The screenshot shows the components of UWP. Please provide the C++ part and the code error.

Desktop Development with C++ is what you should be looking at. I expect you have not installed the C/C++ runtime.

@AndreasWenzel E1696 cannot open source file 'file_name.h'. the code is a default windows console app template with #include <iostream>, and main function with std::cout << "Hello World!\n";. but i've tried with my actual code and it was the same problem.

@MinxinYu-MSFT added screenshot and code, error code E1696 (there are a lot of such errors) and C1083 (one such error related to the 'crtdbg.h' file). There are other errors besides it, but I think they come from the above mentioned errors (E0282, E0020, E0077, E0065).

@429 the errors you get should be copy-pasted verbatim into your question.

@wohlstad I've added errors to the question, I'd really appreciate it if you take a look.

Your installation screenshot shows only WIndows SDK 11 selected, whereas in the project you selected Windows 10 SDK. You probably need to install Windows 10 SDK. Also regarding the errors you posted see this: Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.

@wohlstad I uninstalled the Windows 11 SDK (10.0.22621.0) and installed the Windows 10 SDK (10.0.20348.0) (I have Windows 11 installed). A bunch of errors disappeared, the required version started showing up in the project settings. I selected it, but then i got an error: 'MSB8036 The Windows SDK version 10.0.20348.0 was not found. Install the required version of Windows SDK or change the SDK version in the project property pages or by right-clicking the solution and selecting 'Retarget solution''. I don't understand how this can happen if Visual Studio itself offers me to select this version.

@429 your problem seems to be related to some installation issue, but unfortunately I don't have any other concrete idea. If nothing else helps, you can try to uninstall VS completely, and then reinstall (and maybe select all Windows 10 and 11 SDK versions).

What matters here is what has happened to this machine before you installed VS2022.
It has a memory of the UCRT/SDK having been installed so doesn't install it again.
Having nothing to guess at, one approach is to uninstall and run a cleanup tool

'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits', but there are only directories '8.1' and 'NETFXSDK' there  Try installing the 10.0.22621 sdk from the website: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-sdk/

And try the way: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Cannot-find-Windows-SDK-But-Im-sure-I/10600995#T-N10602171

I was able to solve this problem thanks to your help. First, I uninstalled Visual Studio and all versions of Windows Software Development Kit via Installed Apps. After that I installed Visual Studio, selected only "Desktop development with C++" and unchecked Windows SDK installation. After that I manually installed the Windows SDK from the link. Then I was able to open the project and everything works. At the same time, I have "10.0 (latest installed version)" in the project settings.

Glad to know your problem is solved! I converted the comment to an answer.
